# Can Emotional Detachment Disorder lead to Sociopathy?

Tags: psychology

Both are "learned" (non-genetic) disorders with a small set of overlapping traits/symptoms, usually starting early in life. Are they connected in any way?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  What have you read regarding links between sociopathy and emotional detachment?